# How do I infer based on dataon few KPI which are collected per day on 15 min duration

Tags: tensorflow2.0, aiml

I am new to AI/ML and have attended lots of audit only training on coursera related to AI/ML domain and would like to implement those concepts on real data of product I am working on so that I learn along with doing something fruitful. I am struggling with Data preprocessing  and need some suggestion. I have data of few PM counters collected every 15 mins for whole day, and I have lots of this kind of data collected per day and we often see system restarting because of board temperature exceed for long duration or CPU/MEM stats crossing thresold over the period so would like to have a system which can predict system restart.

```
|KPI  |     0:15|  0:30| .....         |24:00|
|:----|:--------|:-----|.......        |:----|
|mem  |     34  |23    |......         |:10  |
|cpu  |   90    |56    |.....          | 0   | 
|Btemp|  76     | 12   |.....          |63   | 
|xyz  |         |      |.....          |     |
.....
```

So I have csv file with first row as column name and first column values are key/label for data which proceed in next 24x4 columns for data collected for that label every 15 mins. How Can I prepare data out of this csv file using tensorflow etc. I would like to infer/predict malfunctioning based on few KPIs ( not all).